# innodb table count optimization

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've a big innodb table which contain 10.000.000 rows

this query
SELECT count(id) FROM `table_name` takes 4-6 seconds to execute

I need to decrease the query execution time

1) can someone advice how to achieve this without changing the table to MyIsam

2) In case we need to use a MySQL cache how can we turn that ON on the server?

Comment: What's your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value? Please don't say that you're running default MySQL config.

Comment: I increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size from 18mb to 1gb and the execution time took 2.7sec instead of 4-6 sec

Comment: There are several ways to tackle the problem. One is to take care of the count yourself, upon every insert and delete - you save the new row count in a counter table (that you create). You can achieve this by triggers. The other solution is to increase buffer pool to the point where the whole data set fits the RAM. That's what will make the database fly. Also, the default MySQL configuration is present to allow it to run on slow and old machines. It's also making it work extremely slow. If you want proper speed, get several gigs of RAM and increase the buffer pool.

Comment: Do you have any idea what will happen if 1000 trigger queries will execute at the same time?

Comment: I don't know in terms of performance, but all ACID compliant databases are geared for concurrency. The triggers will execute correctly, each one will be isolated and the end result will be correct count stored.

Answer (score 2):

Lie about the count in the application. Really, in rare cases you need exact number.
Approximate row count (but as fast as select count(*) in MyISAM) you can get from

```
SELECT MAX(id) - MIN(id) AS count FROM table
```

if you still need the exact number you can create a table with the count number and update it with a trigger ON INSERT and ON DELETE

Comment: Do you have any idea what will happen if 1000 trigger queries will execute at the same time?

Comment: I tested this way in 5 million rows and it took  0.2940 second only

Comment: The MAX(id) - MIN(id) method has to take into account the value of auto_increment_increment which might not be 1 in some replication scenarios. Also, your record count will be off by 1 with this method.

Answer (score 0):

If your table does not change often, using the MySQL query cache is a good solution.

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 10M
```

Also add index on field 'id' if it doesnt exist.  Also if you are writing an application store count in a seperate table as you insert or update. Its handy.